# Matching the last subnet of IP and put a label

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, ip-address, string-comparison

First, the following is my input sample data:

```
ID  Port Type   IP Address       Correction Flag
1   ETH         135.34.32.62    
1   ETH         135.34.160.61   
1   ETH         100.60.30.62    
1   EXTRA       55.26.76.150    
2   ETH         135.34.32.80    
2   ETH         135.34.160.80   
2   ETH         100.60.30.80    
2   EXTRA       55.26.76.144    
3   ETH         135.34.33.238   
3   ETH         13.534.161.238  
3   ETH         100.60.31.238   
3   EXTRA       55.26.76.77
```

I want to check each `[ID]` where `[Port Type]` = `"ETH"`, whether the last octet of `[IP Address]` is the same or not. IF the last octet is *different*, the `[Correction Flag]` should be *`"Not OK"`*, otherwise, it can be *`"OK"`*.

---

### **Example:**

- for `[ID]` **1**, the last octet for `"ETH"` are:

  > `62`, `61` & `62`

  …so the `[Correction Flag]` is ***`"Not OK"`***.

---

- However, for `[ID]` **2**, the last octets are:

  > `80`, `80` & `80`

  …so the `[Correction Flag]` should be ***`"OK"`***.

---

- `[Port Type]` **EXTRA** is to be *ignored*.

---

Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: What code have you written so far?

Answer (score 2):

No need for VBA here.
Place this formula next to the first IP number and fill down:

```
=IF(AND(B4=B3,B3=B2),IF(AND(RIGHT(C2,3)=RIGHT(C3,3),RIGHT(C2,3)=RIGHT(C4,3)),"OK","Not OK"),"")
```

B2 is the first interface, B3 second, etc.
C2 is the first IP number

Comment: This will not work if the last octat has a single digit for example:135.34.32.6, 135.34.160.6 etc and the Right (C2,3) will take the last 3 values

Comment: That's true. The quick and dirty solution? Replace "." with "..". 
 Something like this: SUBSTITUTE(C2;".";"..")

Comment: Thanks Sam but again, we cannot substitute it at all location as the last octet varies between 1-255 same as all octets. Either I need to find the location of last '.' (maybe using split function) and then count the number of digit after this. I think I have a solution. Will post all the code here later :)

Comment: As I said - it's a quick and _dirty_ solution. Finding the last "." is easy in VBA with InstrRev.

Comment: Thanks, I first changed find last 2 charcter in string,if there is any ".", I replaced it with ".." as: =IFERROR(IF(FIND(".";RIGHT(J2;2));SUBSTITUTE(J2;".";"..");J2);J2) then I applied your formula and everything is perfect. Thanks a lot for this help :) (Please note that I removed a lot of data from excel so the column number is different, also I know how to put formula in excel as my actual automation is way bigger with access involvement here). But thanks a lot for your help :)

Answer (score 2):

As Sam pointed out there is no need for VBA. I would probably go for SUMPRODUCT function - something like this

```
=IF(IF(B2="ETH";SUMPRODUCT((A:A=A2)*(B:B="ETH")*(RIGHT(C:C;3)<>RIGHT(C2;3)));0)>0;"Not OK";"OK")
```

This way it will work no matter how many lines you have or even if the IDs are mixed up.

Comment: This will not work if the last octat has a single digit for example:135.34.32.6, 135.34.160.6 etc and the Right (C2,3) will take the last 3 values

Comment: I would suggest something like finding position of the last dot with FIND("@";SUBSTITUTE(C1;".";"@";3)))  and use RIGHT on difference of LEN of the original and the position. You can use this to replace the 3 in the formula and it will work. But I have to say I like Sam's dot substitute better. It is really elegant way of avoiding the problem :-)

Answer (score 2):

The following array-entered formula will do what you describe.

- There is no requirement that the table be sorted.
- Since they represent the same octet, leading zero's will be ignored (eg `062` and `62` will be considered the same).
- The named ranges (`ID`, `Port_Type`, `IP_Address`) need to be the same size and, for speed of calculation, the smaller the better.
- Be sure to confirm the formula by holding down <kbd>ctrls</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> while hitting <kbd>enter</kbd>.  If you do this correctly, Excel will place braces `{...}` around the formula.

---

```
=IF(B2<>"eth","",IF(SUM(N(FREQUENCY(AGGREGATE(15,6,1/IF(ID=A2,IF(Port_Type="eth",TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(IP_Address,".",REPT(" ",99)),99)))),ROW(INDIRECT("1:" & SUM(--(ISNUMBER(1/IF(ID=A2,IF(Port_Type="eth",TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(IP_Address,".",REPT(" ",99)),99)))))))))),AGGREGATE(15,6,1/IF(ID=A2,IF(Port_Type="eth",TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(IP_Address,".",REPT(" ",99)),99)))),ROW(INDIRECT("1:" & SUM(--(ISNUMBER(1/IF(ID=A2,IF(Port_Type="eth",TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(IP_Address,".",REPT(" ",99)),99)))))))))))>0))=1,"OK","not OK"))
```

[image]

Comment: THanks a lot Ron... Its really helpful.

Comment: One excellent approach to the problem. Useful in similar complex matching problems.